# What are the maximum image dimenions GdImage can process?

Tags: php, image-processing, out-of-memory, gd

PHP GdImage has to process an image by functions like *`imagecreatefromjpeg`* and *`imagecreatefrompng`*.
Given an image of type jpeg or png with known dimensions:

```
  - width in px,
  - height in px,
  - depth in bits (assume max is 32 bits, but could be more?)
```

and knowing:

```
  - memory_limit = xxx; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (in php.ini)
  - memory_get_usage(); - amount of memory allocated to PHP
```

how we can determine if we have enough memory in order to process the image?

Obviously, the bytes occupied will be = `width * height * depth/8`.
But what is the available amount of memory?
Is it correct to write:

```
available_memory_in_bytes = memory_limit_in_bytes - memory_get_usage();
```

Can we use all of it to the last byte for *`imagecreatefrompng`*?
PHP is of decent version 8.1

Comment: I approached this problem in this way: Suppose I want to allow an maximum image area of 2000 x 2000 pixels, which means it could also be 1000 x 4000 pixels. I will test a few images of that area, to see if the system can handle it. And that's it. I would never try to process images that bring a PHP process close to its memory limit. Remember that any operation on the image might require a lot of extra memory.

Comment: What means "a lot of extra memory required"? 2 times, 3 times, a 100 times the image size?

Comment: The amount of memory needed for an image operation depends on the type of operation.

Comment: Maximum width/height of a JPEG is 65535 pixel, so roughly 16GB+a little more, and you should be fine to open any JPEG that possibly exists :) Editing is a different topic though...